# GWT shared CSS styles doesn't work

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I need to use the same style in a few UI Binder templates so I did everything as described in: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Using_an_external_resource .

So I did the following:

1. Created Resources interface:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("shared.css")
    Style style();

    public interface Style extends CssResource {
        String grayedOut();
    }
}
```

2. Created `shared.css` file in the same directory as Resources class:

```
.grayedOut{
    background-color: red;
}
```

3. Added `with` element to UI Binder template:
`<ui:with type="correct.package.Resources" field="res"/>`

4. Added reference to style in UI Binder template: `addStyleNames="{res.style.grayedOut}"`

However it doesn't work. The view is rendered just as grayedOut style wasn't applied at all.

But I observed two things:

1. In Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools I can see that element has assigned an ofuscated style name corresponding to the style I'm trying to add: `class="GAWERH0MI gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent"` (`GAWERH0MI` seem to correspond to my `grayedOut` class) but I can't locate it in "element styles" panel which probably means that this class is empty (no body). (I did experiment and assigned empty class to element with the same effect in that tools).
2. When I change style name in .css, then I'm getting runtime error that style `grayedOut` couldn't be found, which seem to mean that my style class is normally successfully found but from some reason doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to call `ensureInjected()` on a `Resources.Style` instance.

This is done automatically for a `<ui:style>` (because you don't code the `ClientBundle` and `CssResource` interfaces, they are generated for you by UiBinder), but not for any other `CssResource`.

You can use `@UiField Resources res` though, that will be injected with the value of the `<ui:with field="res">`, and thus call `res.style().ensureInjected()` just after the call to `createAndBindUi`.
IMO, you'd however better inject a `Resources` instance into your view and use `@UiField(provided=true)`, and thus either make sure `ensureInjected()` is called before the instance is injected into your view, or choose to call `ensureInjected()` in each of your views. As in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Share_resource_instances

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. But to call Resources.style() I need to have an instance of `Resources` and it is intantiated internaly by UIBinder (`You can make resources available to your template via the <ui:with> element, but at the cost of having them instantiated for you.`) as docs say. So when/how should I invoke this method? Also it's a pity that in docs that I linked there is something that seems like complete, working example but no word is said about invoking `ensureInjected()` which is essential for this code to work :(. It's easy to waste a lot of time copying example from docs that don't work.

Comment: It's a pain to call `ensureInjected`.  Luckily, a call to `ensureInjected` on a second instance of the CssResource works for all CssResources of the same type.  I've taken to a quick `static {GWT.create(); css.ensureInjected();}` at the top of the Java file for every UiBinder.

@Thomas Broyer: it'd be convenient (and not more expensive?) to have ensureInjected called automatically on all CssResource children of `<ui:with>`ed ClientBundles.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk: it's documented in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource_Overview

Comment: @RileyLark: you can also use `@UiField Resources res` that will be injected with the value of the `<ui:with field="res">` and thus call `res.style().ensureInjected()` just after the call to `createAndBindUi`. Having `ensureInjected()` called automatically would mean adding behavior specific to `CssResource` to `<ui:with>` and/or `{expansions}` which are completely generic (not to mention that you `GWT.create` a `ClientBundle`, not a `CssResource`, and you can use none/any/all of the `CssResource`s defined in the `ClientBundle` in your UiBinder template. So no, it's not going to happen.

Comment: Thomas, could you please update your answer to contain statement: " You can use @UiField Resources res that will be injected with the value of the <ui:with field="res"> and thus call res.style().ensureInjected() just after the call to createAndBindUi." because this part was most important for me to solve my problem. When you do it, I will mark your answer as accepted. I think it's much more elegant than static initializers :). Anyways, thanks for your input Riley!

Comment: Ah, somehow I didn't think of `@UiField` to connect xml and java resource instances.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Works the same for any `ui:* element with a `field=""` attribute (`ui:with`, `ui:style`, etc.) and any other element with a `ui:field=""` attribute; `provided=true` works the same for them too.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : Hi , I am new to GWT and GXT. For the Similar question if the person is not using uiBinder then How to solve the issue.

please see this question for more detail. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001146/css-is-not-working-in-gxt/16025107#16025107

Answer (score 2):

ui widget java  file:

```
@UiField
Resources res;
public YourWidget() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));     
        res.style().ensureInjected();
    }
```

ui widget xml file:

```
<ui:with field='res' type="your path to Resource class" />
```

and

```
<g:Label addStyleNames="{res.style.grayedOut}" ui:field="icon"></g:Label>
```