# CSS is not working in GXT

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2, gxt

I am in learning phase of GWT GXT,

I my project some of the css are working fine , but some are showing me a strange behavior .

for login button.

```
logonBtn = new TextButton("Connect");
        logonBtn.setIconAlign(IconAlign.RIGHT);
        logonBtn.setIcon(Resources.INSTANCE.login());
        logonBtn.setStyleName("Project-Button");
```

Css

```
.Project-Button {
    color: Black;
    border: thin outset #FF6600;
    font-family: Courier New, Century Gothic, Times New Roman, Verdana, Arial;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: left center;
    background-color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But when i run the project , this css is not showing any effect on connect button.

In my Project i have i have 6 or 7 TextButton.
But this css is showing effect in only one of these buttons

I tried to use Firebug to see the problem. I see there is no Project-Button css attached with this textButton.

Attached is the Image of fireBug.

If somebody understand this , please explain and give the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Which version of GWT and GXT are you using? Have you try addStyleName()?

Comment: @DiogoSantana : GWT 2.5.1 and GXT 3.0

Comment: And have you tried addStyleName()? I think your .Project-BUtton style should been removed later after you set it.

Comment: @DiogoSantana :  yes i tried addStyleName() also.
Please take a proper view in the Image of firebug area.I dont have these css in my project.I am in learning phase , so i dont know much about GWT and CSS. Is there some default css already in GWT GXT.

Comment: Yes, there is default CSS in GWT GXT. But you can add your styles to components. I think that GXT is removing your style after you set it.

Comment: @DiogoSantana  How to solve ??.. If u need other information, do ask.

Answer (score 1):

If tou change GXT Text button style you have to write your ButtonCellAppereance. GXT button styles too complex as other gxt widgets. [example link about appereance](https://code.google.com/p/gxt-clean-theme/)

[1](https://code.google.com/p/gxt-clean-theme/): http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/ext-gwt-30-theming-and-appearances i started a project on gwt projects as [theme project link](https://code.google.com/p/gxt-clean-theme/)

but i have no more time to develop. good hacking...